# How to select specific string from the output table in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create the script which will resolve the IP address to DNS name and then
ping output computer number:

`$name = Read-Host "Please enter IP address"`

`$comp = Resolve-DnsName $name | select NameHost -First 1`

The output is

### `NameHost`

COMPPL01-NB0128.domain.com ```

When I try to format the output, it gives me

`@{NameHost=COMPPL01-NB0128.domain.com}`

So then I can't ping the result using the command test connection

`Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp`

As I understood, test-connection cmdl is trying to ping the whole string NameHost=COMPPL01-NB0128.domain.com

How can I select only the computer name from that output and ping it?
So far it gives me an error message:

Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer '@{NameHost=COMPPL01-NB0128.domain.com}' failed:
A non-recoverable error occurred during a database
lookup
At line:1 char:1

- Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp
- CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (@{NameHost=COMPPL01-NB0128.domain.com}:String) [Test-Connection], PingException

  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. `Resolve-DnsName 8.8.8.8 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameHost`
   You can use Expand property to get host name value alone.
2. `(Resolve-DnsName 8.8.8.8).NameHost`
   Using the Dot operator to get its properties.